# I want to execute the targetpath of "google chrome" on my desktop

Tags: powershell

I want to execute the targetpath of "google chrome" on my desktop.But it doesn't work.Do you have a solution please?
here is my code:

```
function targetshortcut {
    $path="C:\Users\Public\Desktop"
    $a=get-childitem $path | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -like "Google Chrome"}
    $a.FullName
    $b=$a.FullName
    $sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
    $targetPath1 =  $sh.CreateShortcut($b).TargetPath 
    return $targetPath1
    }
    $targetshortcut1=targetshortcut 
    $targetshortcut1
    

    function executeasadmninsage {
        param (
            $pathco
        )
        Start-Process -FilePath  $pathco -Verb RunAs -PassThru
    }


    $executeasadmninsage1=executeasadmninsage  [string]$targetshortcut1
    $executeasadmninsage1
```

I have this output:

```
 PS D:\powershell1> d:\powershell1\rund.ps1
    C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Google Chrome.lnk
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    Start-Process: D:\powershell1\rund.ps1:33:9
    Line |
      33 |          Start-Process -FilePath  $pathco -Verb RunAs -PassThru
         |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         | This command cannot be run due to the error: Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
function targetshortcut {
    $path="C:\Users\Public\Desktop"
    
    $a=get-childitem $path | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -like "Google Chrome"}
    $b=$a.FullName
    
    $sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
    
   
    $targetPath1 =  $sh.CreateShortcut($b)

    return $targetPath1.TargetPath
    
    
    
    }
    $targetshortcut1=targetshortcut 
    $targetshortcut1
    

    function executeasadmninsage {
        param (
            $pathcoalaclient
        )

        Start-Process -FilePath  $pathcoalaclient -Verb RunAs -PassThru
   
    
    }


    $executeasadmninsage1=executeasadmninsage  $targetshortcut1
    $executeasadmninsage1
```